# JSP page not working in Servlet Program

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, servlet-listeners

Actually i'm trying to display the details obtained from JSP form with servlet. But I'm not able to display the JSP page. But I can see the program entering into the POST method in Servlet.

Here is my code,

**Startup.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="controlServlets" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name"/><br>        
        <input type="text" name="group"/>
        <input type="text" name="pass"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">            
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlServlets</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlets</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controlServlets</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**ControlServlets.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ControlServlets")
public class ControlServlets extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ControlServlets() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


//    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(request,response);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String group = request.getParameter("group");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
            System.out.println("Name :"+ name);
            System.out.println("group :"+ group);
            System.out.println("pass :"+ pass);
            System.out.println("Post method");
    }

}
```

In console,

I can see the following,

```
Name :null
group :null
pass :null
Post method
```

Please Help...

Comment: What happens if you visit /ControlsServlet?name=blah  I see you have mixed upper and lower case servlet names (lower in the JSP form action, upper in the servlet annotation).

Comment: According to amir, You need to change the action name in jsp into `ControlServlets` and web.xml also change into `ControlServlets`

Comment: Yes you have to change the servlet name in your web.xml and form action in your Startup.jsp as ControlServlets which should match the @WebServlet in your ControlServlets.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part I)If you want to use `web.xml` for your application then you need to make following changes :

1)In `Startup.jsp` change the `action` attribute of `<form>` tag to

```
<form action="ControlServlets" method="post"> 
              ↑
```

2)In `web.xml` change the `<servlet-mapping>` to

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>controlServlets</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/ControlServlets</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

3)In `ControlServlets.java` several changes as, in `web.xml` you mentioned

```
<servlet-class>com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlets</servlet-class>
                ↑
```

This is the package name, so you must have first statement in `ControlServlets.java`

```
package com.selenium8x8.servlet;  //in your code it is missing
```

Then, comment following two lines

```
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

and

```
//@WebServlet("/ControlServlets")
```

Now, run application, it will give you desired output.

---

Part II) If you want to use [@WebServlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation, as you did

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ControlServlets")
public class ControlServlets extends HttpServlet {   
  ...
  .....
  .......
}
```

Then, no need for `web.xml`. The above does basically the same as following:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>controlServlets</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlets</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>controlServlets</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/ControlServlets</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For using `@WebServlet` annotation you need `Java EE 6 / Servlet 3.0`

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. Actually its working now. JSP file is present with in WEB-INF. Later i replaced in Webcontent. Then it works fine..